# Is there any way to edit LatTeX code for math expressions in LyX?

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I discovered LyX recently and I liked it. Save one extremely serious drawback here. One can enter new formulae as LaTeX expressions, but once entered they must be edited with LyX tools only. This constraint is so unnatural that I could not believe it is there (taken into account the fact conversion of LyX file to LaTeX format is trivial). For me it ruins the whole enterprise. Is there any plug-in, macro, whatever to circumvent this weird limitation?

P. S. I know it was asked not once in the past, but all the threads I managed to find are a few years old. Maybe someone wrote such a macro/add-on/something.

Comment: Hi, did you check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30841/edit-latex-source-in-lyx?rq=1) ?

Comment: Thank you, I did not see that thread. It basically says that it is not possible (apart from copying LaTeX source, editing it in a third-party program and pasting back into LyX; obviously possible, but rather inconvenient). Again, some time passed since than, so maybe someone comes up with a solution.

Comment: There is an open feature request about this: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7968 See also the links in that issue, to mailing list discussions and other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Torbjørn T. for the links. OK, the picture is pretty clear now. I believe I have my answer, so let me sum all those discussions up.

This issue (or bigger issue of editing the LaTeX code for the whole LyX file, not just math expressions) have been debated for years. There are lots of requests to implement this functionality, but it looks like nobody is willing (or, at least, has resources) to get the job done.

This is a pity (and the deal breaker for me), for it could really come in handy.